# OnCallStateChanged is not working for sim2

Tags: android

Here i have a simple callStateListner it is working perfectly when smartphone receives call on sim1, but when Smartphone receives call on sim2 it is not working at all.

```
private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
      @Override
      public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
          switch (state) {
              case: 0 TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
              // called when someone is ringing to this phone

              Toast.makeText(ctx, 
                      "Incoming: "+incomingNumber, 
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              break;
          }
      }
    }
```

Please help me i out i want to listen for all sims not just sim1.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this prob by my own so i wanna share my experience with u all. Actually the issue was that,

If u create a service that uses OncallStateChanged theb that is not going to listen for sim 2 call if u wanna listen all sims call just create a Broadcast receiver instead of Service. That will do the trick ;)